# Add horizontal shading bands in Excel XY chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have an Excel XY chart, with the following data:

```
Day #1      #2      #3      #4      #5      #6      #7      #8
1   0.30%   0.71%   -0.18%  0.07%   -0.44%  0.63%   0.28%   0.32%
2   -1.24%  -0.03%  -0.52%  -0.23%  -0.59%  0.25%   0.12%   0.11%
3   0.87%   1.19%   0.16%   0.49%   0.18%   1.03%   0.96%   0.70%
4   -0.59%  0.75%   0.13%   0.70%   0.30%   1.33%   1.20%   1.06%
7   1.09%   1.33%   0.32%   1.50%   0.22%   1.38%   1.09%   0.99%
8   -0.58%  0.65%   -0.08%  0.70%   -0.12%  1.13%   0.80%   0.73%
9   1.09%   1.49%   0.51%   1.04%   0.42%   1.57%   1.25%   1.07%
10  0.32%   1.51%   0.74%   1.26%   0.70%   1.90%   1.70%   1.52%
11  -0.12%  1.36%   0.59%   3.11%   0.49%   1.58%   1.45%   1.35%
14  -0.12%  1.24%   0.56%   5.52%   0.49%   1.66%   1.56%   1.33%
15  0.55%   1.58%   0.89%   1.39%   0.79%   1.73%   1.72%   1.58%
16  -0.29%  0.75%   -0.13%  0.04%   -2.08%  -1.54%  -1.93%  -2.66%
17  -0.05%  1.41%   0.74%   8.19%   0.66%   1.66%   1.59%   1.46%
18  0.03%   1.59%   0.93%   5.16%   0.96%   1.98%   1.86%   1.67%
24  0.26%   1.90%   1.33%   1.83%   1.07%   2.35%   2.21%   2.01%
25                              
26                              
27                              
28                              
29                              
30
```

What I would like to do is the following:

- Part of the graph below -1.5%: shaded red (50% transparency)
- Part of the graph between -1.5% and -0.075%: shaded orange (50% transparency)
- Part of the graph between -0.075% and +0.075%: shaded green (50% transparency)
- Part of the graph above 1.5%: shaded red (50% transparency)

I have tried various approaches suggested on what I could find on Google and the closest I have come is this (from [Excel Charts With Horizontal Bands](http://peltiertech.com/excel-charts-with-horizontal-bands/)):
[image]

Close but no cigar... Does anybody have any other suggestion?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Apologies, I should have said. #1, I can't get the first red band to go from -3% to -1.5%, it always starts at -1.5%, which means all subsequent bands are also wrong, and #2 I have this great big gap on the x-axis in the bands that I can't seem to be able to fill.

Comment: It's OK, I managed to solve it by myself. Will post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I have managed to solve this by myself.

I followed the steps described in [Excel Charts With Horizontal Bands](http://peltiertech.com/excel-charts-with-horizontal-bands/) with the following subtle, yet important, differences:

- I changed the primary vertical axes (the one on which the stacked columns are plotted) to start from 0 and have the same span as the secondary vertical axes (the one on which the XY data is plotted). This gets rid of the problem I had with the negative values and the bands not being correct.
- Instead of deleting the primary vertical axes (which undoes the previous scaling step), I just made it invisible by setting tick marks and labels to 'None'.
- I changed the secondary vertical axes to have the horizontal axes cross at a specified value corresponding to the minimum value of the vertical axes (-3% in my case). This moves the horizontal axes to the bottom of the plot.
- I set the gap width of the stacked columns to 0, which gets rid of the great big gap I had initially.
- I deleted the primary axes titles (both horizontal & vertical), and added titles for the secondary axes (both horizontal & vertical). The titles were on the wrong side of the graph compared to the labels and tick marks, because the main XY data was moved from primary to secondary axes.
- I deleted the legend entries for the stacked columns
- I added the major gridlines for the secondary vertical axes.

Hopefully, this will help somebody with the same problem!